# Claims based Authorization

Tags: adfs2.0

Planning to use ADFS to federate. One big challenge that we find is that not all applications are claims aware, also every application has a different role based access. In such a how can we achieve 100% SSO Authentication and Authorization using Identity Claims.

In case ADFS cannot support such a requirement, What other vendor solutions are available which can supports such a requirement.

Answer (score 1):

A claims-aware application in the .NET world uses WIF / WS-Federation to get a set of claims in a SAML token which are then used to control user access and functionality.

ADFS only answers to WS-Federation or SAML requests.

So to get a non claims-aware application to use AFDS, the application needs to be changed to add support for either of these protocols.

Refer: [SAML : SAML connectivity / toolkit](http://nzpcmad.blogspot.co.nz/search/label/SAML) and the links inside the post.

Or you could go the other way and put something like an OpenAM agent around the applications and then federate OpenAM and ADFS.

ADFS on Server 2012 R2 has a new feature as part of the Web Application proxy, refer [Create a Non-Claims-Aware Relying Party Trust](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn508281.aspx).

There's a walkthrough here -  [Walkthrough Guide: Connect to Applications and Services from Anywhere with Web Application Proxy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn280943.aspx)

and a good example here -  [First Impressions – AD FS and Window Server 2012 R2 – Part II](http://blog.auth360.net/2014/01/07/first-impressions-ad-fs-and-window-server-2012-r2-part-ii/).